# Why is CreateInstance<ProdDetail>() trying to reference JAMS.AM.AMPRODMATL in 2020R2?

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to execute a CreateGraph() statement to make a ProdDetail graph in 2020R2. Here is the original line of code:

[image]

Here is the error I'm getting:

[image]

I have no clue how it is trying to reference a now non-existing library, especially given the fact that I have quantified the exact library to reference ProdDetail from.

Comment: what is ProdDetail ? I don't think its a graph in 202R2. Probably in JAMS which is an add-on product.

Comment: It used to be a page in Manufacturing JAMS. Maybe they changed the name. I'll look into that. EDIT: After doing a fast search in VS. I can see it under App_Data/CodeReposity/PM.Objects.AM/AM/ProDetail.cs. The file appears to still be in use.

Comment: FYI JAMS was acquired by Acumatica and the manufacturing features are now integrated in Acumatica core product.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure there is a reference in your extension library to PX.Objects.AM.
The graph ProdDetail is used in this library.

[image]